# Output is not printed in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to Oracle. I write a simple PL/SQL to store the snap_id into variable and print the snap_id. If i use exception handling with null value, then the output is not printing even though there are some values from sql query. If i remove the exception block, then the results are printed correctly. Why does the exception block is not taken? What should be added in the code?
Thanks in advance!

Oracle database version: 19.3.0.0.0 RU

**With exception:**

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
snap number;
BEGIN
select max(dhsq.snap_id) into snap
        from dba_hist_sqlstat dhsq
        inner join dba_hist_snapshot dhss on (dhss.snap_id = dhsq.snap_id)
        where dhsq.sql_id='38mkqq9vpu6vf';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(snap);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  snap := NULL;
END;
/
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Output without exception:**

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
snap number;
BEGIN
select max(dhsq.snap_id) into snap
        from dba_hist_sqlstat dhsq
        inner join dba_hist_snapshot dhss on (dhss.snap_id = dhsq.snap_id)
        where dhsq.sql_id='38mkqq9vpu6vf';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(snap);  2    3    4    5    6    7    8
  9  END;
 10  /
743 <========
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

The below output is a static one which will be retained for 7 days. So, this sql_id is saved in disk and will not return zero rows.

```
select max(dhsq.snap_id) from dba_hist_sqlstat dhsq inner join dba_hist_snapshot dhss on (dhss.snap_id = dhsq.snap_id) where dhsq.sql_id='38mkqq9vpu6vf';

MAX(DHSQ.SNAP_ID)
-----------------
              743
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this - but wouldn't expect to be able to. Are you sure that `sql_id` did actually exist when both blocks were executed? (You won't get `no_data_found` anyway, even if there is no data - because the aggregate function will still return null - so the exception block isn't doing anything.)

Comment: Yes, snap_id will be collected 24*7 in the database and the sql is executed recursively. So result will be always valid without null. Why 743 is printed in the second code, if aggregate function return null?

Comment: Cannot replicate your issue [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MEHqphZ4). Please [edit] the question to include a complete [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements that replicate the issue.

Comment: The aggregate function will return null if there is no data. If the `sql_id` exists in the statistics and snapshot history then it will return the highest matching `snap_id`. It appears that when you ran your first block there was no statistic and/or snapshot data with that `sql_id`; by the time you ran the second there was. (Or you ran them the other way and it was removed). What happens if you re-run both blocks now? And can you verify whether the `sql_id` exists in each table manually, before you run each block?

Comment: Use stable sample data to demonstrate the issue, then investigate the reason why your query doesn't return what you want. This is not related to the exception as described above.

Comment: Yes i tried this multiple times but it behave in same way. I even tried a simple test case but the procedure executes fine in it without null. I hope the issue is with joins and aliases with two views

Comment: There shouldn't be any way the PL/SQL exception handler could influence the query. If this is really reproducible then please include the full Oracle database version and patch level in your question. It might also be interesting to see if the same thing happens with other exceptions, or other queries - including against your own real (can be dummy) tables, which we ought to be able to reproduce.

Comment: The test case works fine without using any joins or aliases. Only this particular query shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something else here because selecting max value into variable will never raise NO_DATA_FOUND. It will, in case of no rows, return null. That means the EXCEPTION is irrelevant in the code from the question. Having it in the code or not - doesn't change anything.
Example:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    snap        Number;
    null_snap   Number;
BEGIN
    Select
        Nvl(Max(NUM), 0),
        Max(NUM) 
    InTo null_snap, snap
    From 
        (Select 'A' "LETTER", 99 "NUM" From Dual)
    Where 
        LETTER = 'B';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NULL_SNAP = ' || To_Char(null_snap) || ' ***');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SNAP = ' || To_Char(snap) || ' ***');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        snap := NULL;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERR - ' || SQLERRM);
END;
--  anonymous block completed
--  NULL_SNAP = 0 ***
--  SNAP =  ***
```

It is clear that there are no rows matching the where condition and the Max(NUM) returned Null which is changed into 0 with Nvl() function.
If there was different select into - without the max function like

```sql
...
Select
    NUM 
InTo snap
...
```

then the exception would be raised and the code above would result as

```sql
--  anonymous block completed
--  ERR - ORA-01403: no data found
```

Finaly if there is at least one row then it would look like this

```sql
...
Select
        Nvl(Max(NUM), 0),
        Max(NUM) 
    InTo null_snap, snap
    From 
        (Select 'A' "LETTER", 99 "NUM" From Dual)
    Where 
        LETTER = 'A';
...
```

resulting as

```sql
anonymous block completed
NULL_SNAP = 99 ***
SNAP = 99 ***
```

Your code works fine here with or without the EXCEPTION...
Regards...